# Excessive Firefox CPU and RAM usage (+ choppy audio)?

Tags: audio, memory, firefox, ram, cpu-usage

I'm trying to use both Firefox Quantum 68.10.0 ESR 64-bit and TOR browser 9.5.1 (= based on said Firefox 68.10.0 ESR) on a Linux Mint Debian Edition 4 machine. What's with the resources squander of these browsers?

Both show up in `gnome-system-monitor` with several processes, for Firefox Quantum it's

```
firefox.real
Web Content
WebExtensions
```

and for TOR browser it's

```
firefox-bin
Web Content
WebExtensions
```

The culprits are the two main processes, **`firefox.real`** and **`firefox-bin`** (one per instance), and the process **`Web Content`** (up to several per instance). Just running a YouTube video or surfing around causes CPU load to spike to **40-60%** and RAM usage to **600-900 MB**, with the latter usually not decreasing by itself anywhere fast enough. To make matters worse, the audio in all YouTube videos is extremely choppy, i.e. there is a high-frequency "glitching/crackling" that directly modulates with the volume (if someone speaks up, the crackling gets worse).

What's the matter with Firefox these days? Just 10 years ago, this would have simply and inevitably crashed/freezed any normal PC - as a matter of fact: Both *do tend to freeze-crash* any live Linux system running on USB 3.0 flash drives or external SSDs with high reliability, which is why I cannot use them on live systems.

How can a mundane web browser demand this much resources and underperform compared to literally any of its competitors? It feels like looking after a badly spoiled, hyper-entitled brat - and it's *both* Firefox *and* TOR browser which are affected, so **clearly** this is an underlying Firefox issue. Disabling all extensions, disabling Javascript, and resetting all settings is not helping, neither is purging and reinstalling. Plus, I'm positive that more people are experiencing exactly the same issues as anyone can easily tell from a quick web search - but Mozilla so far has not been able or willing to present working solutions. If I'm wrong with this statement, I would be glad to be pointed towards the right source!

What **exactly** is causing this abnormal behaviour? Are there any diagnostics that one could run?

I'm happy for any suggestions and will provide any information requested. Furthermore, this topic will be up for bounty shortly. Looking forward to your ideas!

Comment: I observed issues similar to what you describe with faulty graphics drivers. Is OpenGL available on your system and fully functional?

Comment: I occasionaly (but rarely) experience those choppy audio issues in Firefox. But every mainstream browser is a resource hog. I would not blame them, but the cranky, bloated webpages out there, with which the browsers have to deal.

Comment: @Quasimodo: Other browsers such as Chromium does not seem to have this problem. It really is specific to Firefox and it's not a new issue as well

Comment: @Hermann: How do I check the OpenGL status on Linux? When doing `inxi -Gx`, I get this: `Graphics:  Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] RV515/M54 [Mobility Radeon X1400] driver: radeon v: kernel Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.4 driver: ati,radeon unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa resolution: 1400x1050~60Hz OpenGL: renderer: ATI RV515 v: 2.1 Mesa 18.3.6`

Comment: All browsers do this now, all the blink/webkit/gecko rendering engine + javascript engine ones do anyway. Firefox just looks/acts worse because it's running all tabs in one thread, whereas chromium/safari/chrome/vivalidi/opera and other webkit/blink based ones run each tab in a separate thread. I'm surprised that this is the first time you've  noticed this, I was not able to use firefox without noscript and ublock origin for years because of this issue, plus modern websites are now loading huge javascript applications just to display a  page

Comment: @Lizardx: Actually, I remember that many years ago I stopped using Firefox, IIRC also for high loads and frequent crashes. Then things seemed to have improved a little (I'm also using HTTPS Everywhere, NoScript, and UBO) and TOR browser came waltzing along... Currently, it's just a **huge** mess. I remember a time, where a 700 MHz CPU and 512 MB RAM was considered high spec - everything was snappy/fast, from the OS GUIs to the web browsers...it feels like computing performance has gone through the roof, while user experience is becoming worse

Comment: The more things you insert into this process, the more likely heavy ram use will occur, though I find ublock origin really helps overall, but firefox from what I can see suffers from some type of issue where it's ram use goes up and up the longer you have a bunch of tabs open. Firefox some years back had a memory leak that stayed around for years because the devs refused to admit it existed, that was fixed finally, but I see something that looks like a ram leak now too.

Comment: Exactly! This only makes sense if Firefox was integrated in some kind of a distributed computing network and doing bitcoin mining or whatever... Unfortunately, disabling Javascript does **not** solve the problem and judging by Mozilla's long history of "dealing" with memory issues, this seems to be more of a political problem than a software engineering one. I'm still hoping for a software engineering solution, though

Comment: No, last time it was a true memory leak, which is a bug, it lingered for ages because the devs were running powerful machines with tons of ram, and didn't notice it. I've noticed that this happens because I use suspend to ram and firefox slowly starts to eat more and more ram, until it finally crashes, then it restarts with session restore, same tabs, and uses a fraction of the ram it was using when it crashed. Ram use right now: 4158.1 MiB for ff. After crash, about 1/4 of that.